# Python Pandas - DataFrame groupby assignment resulting in SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The line:

```
df["max_performance_factor_per_strat"] = df.groupby(["dsp_strategy_id"])[
    "performance_factor"
].transform(max)
```

is throwing the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How do I resolve this? What is causing it?

Comment: At some point _before_ this provided code you have unsafely subset your DataFrame. Either `new_df = df[cols]` or `new_df = df[mask]` when it should have been `new_df = df[cols].copy()` or `new_df = df[mask].copy()` The warning is letting you know that `df[mask]['col'] = value` may not work because `df[mask]` may produce a copy and recommends that you use `df.loc[mask, 'col'] = value` but that message is not clear here since you're doing something like `new_df = df[mask]` then later doing `new_df[col] = value` which looks to pandas like a (deferred) `df[mask][col] = value` call.

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed in

[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

it's a false positive warning that can be safely disabled as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Hope this helped you out.